# 5v ALDL 8192 Baud to esp32

Tags: uart, level-shifting

I've been working on a diagnostics program for my old diesel, I need the TX/RX pins of my esp32 to connect to the 1 wire ALDL port. I believe I've found a suitable way using the following circuit
[image: Interface 1]

Im aware this does not include level shifting from 5v to 3v3 which I believe I just need a suitable level shifter ic to accomplish, my question here is how does this circuit allow 1 wire to 2 wire communication? Wouldn't the diode in that orientation not allow the TX pin to send its data?

Here is another interface circuit I found, I'm not sure how both of these circuits could be accomplishing the same thing. Could anyone provide some insight into this? I feel like the 2nd circuit is the better way to go but Id rather not if the first one does the same thing more or less somehow.

Also can anyone explain the oscillator in the circuit below, is it required for the interface or is it simply the clock for the mcu?
[image]

Here is the explanation from the writeup on the second circuit

"One design issue with the microcontroller UART is that the transmit pin on the microcontroller is held high when inactive.  Holding the serial line high when inactive is extremely common and used in many serial communication methods. If the transmit pin of the microprocessor was connected directly to the ECU serial line it would be held high when the ECU was trying to bring the line low for communication. A transistor is used on pin PD1 of the microcontroller, as seen in Figure 7, to isolate the transmit line. The ALDL serial line is held high by the ECU, the PNP transistor only brings the serial data line low when the transmit pin on the microcontroller is brought low.

In order to prevent the receive UART from being filled with data that is being transmitted from the AVR microcontroller a transistor is use to isolate the receive line. The microcontroller sets pin PD5 high when transmitting so the receive UART on pin PD0 does not see the data being transmitted. When the microcontroller brings pin PD5 low the transistor is able to pull the receive UART pin, PD0, low when the ALDL line is low. An ALDL serial activity LED was added for debugging purposes. The LED comes on when the ALDL serial line is pulled low and remains off when there is no activity on the line, since the inactive state of a serial line is high.

To accommodate for the off standard baud rate of 8192 a crystal oscillator of 19.6608 Mhz was selected. At this clock rate the divider in the UART baud rate register, defined as UBRR, works out to zero percent error. As seen in the equation below an exact baud rate of 8192 is achieved with a UBRR register setting of 149 and a crystal oscillator of 19.6608 Mhz."

Comment: Why would you use 8192 baud instead of a common rate like 4800 or 9600 baud?

Comment: Old gm systems from late 80s to 95 use 8192 baud for communication with the technician diagnostics terminals, the ecu wont understand what's being sent otherwise   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALDL

Comment: The circuit with Atmeha324P won't work because MCU is missing AVCC supply. Other than that, the clock is for the MCU, but of course the clock will end up being divided down to baud rate.

Comment: I figured it was for that, thank you for clarifying! I was only planning on using the interface from it but with an esp32

Comment: The circuit would need level translators or some modifications for the esp32 3V3 logic levels.